# How do i submit a form with javascript that submits another form

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

So on my website I got a pay-pal submit and another form I want submitting when onclick pay-pal button here is the code:

```
    <form id="info_on_pay" action="" method="post" target="">
          First name:<br>
          <input type="input" name="First_Name"><br>
          Last name:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Last_Name"><br>
          Email:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Email"><br>
          Target URL:<br>
          <input type="input" name="Target">
        </form>
      </div>
        <div id="price_area"><h1>£10</h1></div>
        <div id="button_placement">
      <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="KG8PZVUP3AGVE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions would be helpful thank you.

Comment: Hi Tim, you should have shown some own effort. What did you try? Where did you fail?

Comment: Well I found that rather rude "should of shown some own effort" I'll have you know I’m coding my own website from scratch. While guessing your talking about the JavaScript, I don't understand it that well or learnt it that well.

Comment: How is that rude? I undertand that you are in a learning process. You still should have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

tried like this..?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="id1" action="" >
  <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>
<form id="id2" action="" >
  <input type="text" name="name" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

```js
$("#id2").submit(function(eve){
  eve.preventDefault();
  $("#id1").submit();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#id2").submit();
  },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#info_on_pay" ).submit(function( event ) {

$( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

**This should work. Where I had target would be the ID of your second form. You'll need to give it one it doesnt seem to have an ID**